# String Issues in kata

Tags: java, string

Hello guys I am starting to learn some java.
I found Codewars.com as a great way to exercise and also to learn.

i got this instructions:

```
accum("abcd") -> "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
accum("RqaEzty") -> "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"
accum("cwAt") -> "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

this is what i managed to so far i would like if someone can explain to me how return it correctly and also how to add the "-" at the end of each letter.

```
 for (int i = 1; i<=x.length(); i++){
    return x.substring(i-1,i).toUpperCase();
    for (int j = 1; j<i; j++){
        return x.substring(i-1,i);
    }
}

OUTPUT:
A
M
m
I
i
i
T
t
t
t
```

Thank you for the support.

Comment: You need to understand what the `return` statement does. You need to stay in your `accum` function, and build up a `String` or `StringBuilder`, and only `return` to the calling function when complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a `return` the code after can't be executed, you just read each char, then multiply it by the index

You can easily do this with a `StringBuilder`

```
static String accum(String value) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(value.toUpperCase().charAt(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            sb.append(value.toLowerCase().charAt(i));
        }
        sb.append("-");
    }
    return sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf("-")).toString();
}
```

With Java11 and `String.reapeat`

```
static String accum(String value) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
        sb.append(value.toUpperCase().charAt(i));
        sb.append(String.valueOf(value.toLowerCase().charAt(i)).repeat(i));
        sb.append("-");
    }
    return sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf("-")).toString();
}
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` is good for performances but it may be more difficult to read for a beginner.